# Proj4JS projection definition for rotated pole

Tags: gis, projection, proj4js

I am trying to define a rotated pole projection in Proj4JS where the north pole is now is 48N and 176E.  I haven't been able to find any other example of rotated-poles in Proj4JS so I have tried to convert one I found for PROJ.4.

```
proj4.defs('myProjection', '+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=latlon +o_lon_p=-176 +o_lat_p=48 +lon_0=0 +a=1 +to_meter=0.0174532925199');
```

That line of JS is run without problem, but when I try to use that projection

```
proj4('EPSG:4326', 'myProjection', [175, -41]);
```

I get this error

```
uncaught exception: myProjection
```

I've tried replacing the projection definition the one for WGS84 and it works fine, so I believe my use of the function is correct, it's the parameters in that string that I am unsure of.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is the so-called [Azimuthal Equidistant projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection). It's the best choice for measuring true distances radiating away from a center point.

If this is what you're looking for, [I asked a similar question a while back](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118125/proj4js-is-this-correct-implementation-of-azimuthal-equidistant-relative-to-an) over on GIS.SE, and for the coordinate you provided (48N, 176E), you could declare the Proj4js projection definition as so..

`Proj4js.defs["CUSTOM:10001"] = "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=48.0 +lon_0=176.0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";`

I hope it helps.